# Do I need an article in a phrase that can be regarded as a unit?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I wrote:

> For example, in English where **phrases in sentence** have an almost fixed order, using the phrase structure is more common.

I know *sentence* is countable and perhaps I should say *phrases in a sentence* but I think maybe the whole phrase can be used as a unit without any article? Especially that I speak generally. Am I right?

Comment: For some reason without an article it doesn't sound right to me...  You could just reverse them and say "sentence parts".

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the article if you make the nouns plural. However you have some disagreement with singular and plural.

You can either say:

> For example, in English where phrase**s** in sentence**s**...

or

> For example, in English where phrase**s** in **a** sentence...

or

> For example, in English where **a** phrase in a sentence...

---

However, neither option sounds quite right to me as a native speaker. I'd probably reword the entire sentence:

> For example, in English, using the phrase structure is more common because the phrases in a sentence have an almost fixed order.

Comment: Thanks, it seems in English for generic nouns they use plural or it should be a mass noun, while in my native language, Persian, a singular noun can be generic, as **sentence** for the concept of *sentence*. Moreover, we don't have definitive article

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would say:

> For example, in English where phrases in **sentences** have an almost fixed order, using the phrase structure is more common.

*a sentence* is also OK. I don't see any difference without more context.

Though unlikely, it is possible to use your sentence if you consider "phrases in sentence" as a separate term (with some meaning in context). Then:

> For example, in English where *phrases in sentence* have an almost fixed order, using the phrase structure is more common.

If you say this with a short pause before and after "phrases in sentence" you might understand this better.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't mean the last interpretation, then I think I should use *phrases in sentences*

Comment: I just threw that in for extra information. It might be helpful in another context.